# Laravel - How to optimize MIN - MAX - orderBy queries?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-optimization

My code in Laravel is:

```
Car::selectRaw('*,
    MIN(car_prices.price) AS min_price,
    MAX(car_prices.price) AS max_price,
    MAX(car_prices.updated_at) AS latest_update')
->leftJoin('car_prices', 'car_prices.car_id', 'cars.id')
->groupBy('car_prices.car_id')
->orderBy('latest_update', 'desc')
->paginate(10);
```

It takes long time to run until throwing error:

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

The count of records in `cars` table is 100,000 and 6,000,000 in `car_prices`.

The tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=110001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `car_prices` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `car_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `car_prices_car_id_foreign` (`car_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5506827 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The query:

```
select count(*) as aggregate
    from `cars`
    left join `car_prices`
    on `car_prices`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`
    group by `car_prices`.`car_id`;

select *,
    MIN(car_prices.price) AS min_price,
    MAX(car_prices.price) AS max_price,
    MAX(car_prices.updated_at) AS latest_update from `cars`
    left join `car_prices`
    on `car_prices`.`car_id` = `cars`.`id`
    group by `car_prices`.`car_id`
    order by `latest_update` desc
    limit 10
    offset 0;
```

How can I optimize it? Should I cache the data? Or there is some better query than this?

- My hard disk is SSD
- Value of innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
- The number of writes/inserts approximately 1000/second from 10AM - 02PM and before and after this period there are much less requests.

Comment: is this statement necessary (->orderBy('latest_update', 'desc'))?

Comment: You can try indexing

Comment: When you ask questions about query optimization, always include the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for the table involved in the query. Don't make us guess at the data types, indexes, and constraints you have. Help us to help you!

Comment: And please provide the generated SQL.  The issues are easier for some of us to spot in SQL than in one of the _many_ front end packages.

Comment: Which table is `latest_update` in?  It makes a _big_ difference in optimization.

Comment: Is there a reason for `LEFT` instead of a plain join?

Comment: As I read it, the UI is unreasonable.  You are asking the user to paginate through 100,000 rows in 10-row pages.  That's `10K pages!!  Re-think the UI, then come back for more abuse.

Comment: Yes because I want to sort it by `latest_update`. @OMR

Comment: It is already indexed but again it is too slow. I think there is a need for better algorithm. @STA

Comment: I edited the question with structure and query provided. @BillKarwin

Comment: There is no column `latest_update` in tables. It is an alias. And yes there is a need for `LEFT` because sometimes it might have no record in `car_prices` but the `car` should exist. @RickJames

Answer (score 0):

U need to either have better car table unique index latest_update or remove ->orderBy('latest_update', 'desc') in query. and sort it after receiving the results

U can check the performance  in mysql with explain

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM car order by latest_update desc;

/// Check this [https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/#:~:text=the%20last%20decade.-,Explain,DELETE%20%2C%20REPLACE%20%2C%20and%20UPDATE%20](https://www.exoscale.com/syslog/explaining-mysql-queries/#:%7E:text=the%20last%20decade.-,Explain,DELETE%20%2C%20REPLACE%20%2C%20and%20UPDATE%20).

and [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html#:~:text=The%20EXPLAIN%20statement%20provides%20information,%2C%20REPLACE%20%2C%20and%20UPDATE%20statements.&text=That%20is%2C%20MySQL%20explains%20how,joined%20and%20in%20which%20order](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html#:%7E:text=The%20EXPLAIN%20statement%20provides%20information,%2C%20REPLACE%20%2C%20and%20UPDATE%20statements.&text=That%20is%2C%20MySQL%20explains%20how,joined%20and%20in%20which%20order).

Basically u need to optimize (better index) your DB table "car" so that it perform well

And other thing u might to try increasing execution time
In php.ini  u need to set max_execution_time = 600 or something more to just check how much time it needed to complete execution.
https://www.codewall.co.uk/increase-php-script-max-execution-time-limit-using-ini_set-function/

Comment: Because of the `LIMIT`, it is far more efficient to sort in the server.  Otherwise, a zillion rows must be shoveled from the server to the client.  _This_, alone would make the query even slower.

Answer (score 0):

In both queries,

```
GROUP BY cars.id
```

This is instead of using `car_prices`.`car_id`, which might be missing because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Once you have done that, the first query (with just the `COUNT`) can drop the `JOIN`.  And then the `GROUP BY` becomes redundant:

```
select  count(*) as aggregate
    from  `cars`
```

The second query has issues.

With the current design, you must go through all of both tables.  Ugh.

Also...  If there are no prices for a given car, it will have `NULL` for `latest_update`, therefore it will sort at the end of the 100,000 rows.  Given that, you may as well not display those cars; this would simplify the query enough to be better optimized.

If you need to list the cars for which you have no prices, make that a separate request in the UI.  That query will be a `LEFT JOIN .. IS NULL` and won't need the `MAX()s`.

But, I am still concerned about the 10,000 pages that the user needs to paginate through.

Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Toss `created_at` and `updated_at`, if you aren't using them for anything.

After that, `cars` is simply a mapping between `id` and `name`.  This *might* allow you to avoid going through `cars`.  Instead do something like

```
SELECT  ( SELECT name FROM cars WHERE id = x.car_id ) AS name, 
        ...
     FROM ...
```

Another thought that whenever you add a row to `car_prices`, you update `updated_at` in `cars`.  This would allow you to find the 10 cars entirely in `cars`.

Decide what you are willing to sacrifice.

**More**

Note:  With MyISAM, a slow `SELECT` blocks `UPDATE`.  With InnoDB, the can run in parallel; the `SELECT` uses the values before the `UPDATE`.  Either way, the select is at some "point in time".  But InnoDB allows more parallelism.

It is a tradeoff.  A small slowdown in updates to achieve a big speedup on selects.  (No, I don't know for sure that my suggestion is "faster")

Some further questions to analyze the tradeoff:

- Disk:  HDD or SSD?
- Value of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` (after you change to InnoDB).
- How much traffic?  As a first cut, is the number of writes--insert/delete--more than 100/second?

Comment: Thank you @RickJames but there is another problem now. In the last paragraph you said to add a column for price update date in order not to sort it with `car_prices` table. Because there are approximately 200 users online that each of them do update and insert prices for about 1000 products per 15 minutes. These updates and inserts would take more time than selects. What should I do now?

Comment: @kodfire - True.  See my addition.

Comment: Edited with the details. @RickJames

Comment: @kodfire - The 1000 inserts per second is coming from a program, not humans?  If so, are they batched.  Example:  you read 4K data points from one source and it takes a few seconds or minutes to shovel them into the database?  Meanwhile another 7K records are coming from another source.  Etc.  If so, and they can be combined into a single `INSERT`, performance will be much better.  (I can't image 14M records being typed in by humans!)

Comment: Let me tell you the scenario. There are 1000 cars that the user wanna change their prices. So she/he will edit her/his previous price for those specific cars. I can make it better by collecting same prices into an array and update all cars that the user wanna change them to 15900 (As an example) but again in the worst situations the user has set the prices differently and none of them are the same. Each user in the worst situation update 1000 price for her/his cars maximum and it might get 200 users on that second. So 1000 * 200 = 200000 requests!!! @RickJames

Comment: @kodfire - Is that 1000 a single upload of a CSV?  If so, that can be handled literally 10 times as fast as 1000 one-car web page changes.  If the 1000 changes are turned into a 1000 one-car changes, that is inefficient and should be fixed.

Comment: @kodfire - Please start a new Question.  In it, we can focus on issues of speeding up `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.  Provide details on how the data comes in.  (This Question focuses on the `SELECT` and already has several suggestions.)

Answer (score 0):

The query you have used is not apt for such large tables. instead whenever entry coming to the table **car_prices** set a operation and take minimum and maximum value and store it in the cars table. or you can setup a crone for this.